# What is this car?

Tags: vehicle-identification

[image]

Seen in Paris, France
It looked "new", but seemed to have some
old style, and didn't have any branding I know.
What is it?

Comment: Can you post any other pictures? The license plate is LT, for Lithuania, so could be an old soviet car

Comment: Agree with GdD ... there's too much glare and not enough car ... more pics would surely be helpful, such as the side so detail can be seen.

Comment: Sadly I don't have more pictures... It indeed looks like some old soviet cars to me, but it was definitely looking as new (ie not old restored, but like just produced)

Answer (score 4):

I think I've found her! It's indeed a modern car, a special unique made "Volga" by a russian company called A:Level.
It's based on a BMW 6-series, which seems to have been transformed to match some old Gaz Volga from soviet era style, but perfectly modern.
It's a convertible, and looks not bad!

Some info:
http://exclusivestreetcars.forumpro.fr/t245-quand-les-russes-travaillent-la-carrossserie
https://youtu.be/iSstao9Dmts
http://ru.autopedia.wikia.com/wiki/GAZ_V8_Volga_Convertible